# secure authentication with access/refresh token and axios (cookies? local storage?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm building an authentication system with access and refresh token in react, with a nodejs backend.

Currently, I'm only using access token which are valid for 24 hours. I'm setting them in a httpOnly-cookie on the server, only send over https (secure: true). With axios, I add the withCredentials-option to the request, and the cookie (with the token) is send to the server.

I have made a little axios tweak to work with access/refresh tokens. My code so far:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api',

// add the accessToken to the request config when making a request
// with axios
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
  if (accessToken) {
    config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
  }
  return config;
}, (error) => {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

// check if a status 401 is send back
// this means the access token is invalid
// do a request to the server to refresh the access token with the refresh token
// and repeat the initial request when the new access token is received
axios.interceptors.response((response) => {
  // status 200 OK
  // just return the response
  return response;
}, (error) => {
  // store the original request (passed with the error)
  const origReq = error.config;
  const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken');
  // origReq.retried is just to prevent an infinite loop of retries
  if (refreshToken && !origReq.retried) {
    origReq.tried = true;
    return axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: `${apiUrl}/auth/refresh-access-token`,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${refreshToken}`
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      // store the new access token
      localStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.data.accessToken);
      // retry the original request
      return axios(origReq);
    });
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Basically I've created 2 interceptors: 1 for the request (to add the access token to the request) and 1 for the response (to check for the response status, if status = 401 then access token is invalid so refresh the access token first with the refresh token).

Some notes about this code:

- In production, all requests to the API will happen over HTTPS.
- Is putting the access/refresh token in the Authorization-header ok? In some code examples, I see them putting the refresh token just in the POST body. What's the most efficient/secure way? In my code, I check the Authorization-header and this works, but I want to know whats best.
- In this code example, I'm storing the access and refresh token in **LocalStorage**. I have found [this medium article](https://medium.com/@benjamin.botto/secure-access-token-storage-with-single-page-applications-part-1-9536b0021321) but I can't read it, it should contain information about how to securely store tokens. [This article](https://blog.logrocket.com/jwt-authentication-best-practices/#:%7E:text=A%20JWT%20needs%20to%20be,storage%20(or%20session%20storage).) says a JWT token (like I use for my access/refresh tokens) should be stored in a httpOnly cookie, like I do now? But how can I inject the value of the httpOnly-cookies in my axios requests? I know it works `with withCredentials: true`, but would then the access ànd the refresh token be sent with every request? Maybe the response interceptor is obsolete then, because I can check the refresh token directly on the server when an access token is invalid.
- If I'm correct, I don't need explicit CSRF-protection when I'm sending my tokens via the Authorization-header ([source](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/170388/do-i-need-csrf-token-if-im-using-bearer-jwt) -> first answer). But I do need it when I'm switching to httpOnly-cookies with the `withCredentials: true` header, am I correct?

Thanks in advance!